# Image gets corrupted/merged with other image on upload

Tags: android, image, file-upload, image-uploading, retrofit

I am uploading multiple images (sequentially) clicked from android camera. 
I am using multipart form data to upload image with retrofit library . Some images received are correct . Sometimes two images get merged into each other and image gets corrupted. I don't know that could be reason behind this.
Any help would be appreciated

[image]

Comment: Please add the context a bit - where it is getting uploaded, what is the server to do that, what javascript form you are using. Thanks.

Comment: How do you merge these two photos?

Comment: kinshuk4 i am uploading through http multipart form data from android phone.
@NikolaDespotoski these were actually two different photos which got merged on upload , that is the bug actually. I dont know why is this happening.